# Can spinnaker deploy into a non-default AWS VPC?

Tags: amazon-vpc, spinnaker

I currently have spinnaker deployed into my default VPC. However I'd like to setup my production and staging environments into two separate VPCs. Spinnaker appears to only deploy into the default VPC. Is it possible to deploy into another VPC other than the VPC spinnaker is deployed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spinnaker looks for the `Name` tag on the VPCs and subnets to present those as options when deploying.

If you had two vpcs: with names `vpc0` and `vpc1`

Then in those vpcs you create subnets, and put for the Name tag on each of those with the format:

```
<subnet name>.<availability zone>.<vpc name>
```

e.g.

- internal.us-east-1c.vpc0
- internal.us-east-1c.vpc1
- external.us-east-1d.vpc0
- external.us-east-1d.vpc1

Then when you are deploying, you will pick a subnet in the deploy dialog and you will see in the dropdown:

- internal (vpc0)
- internal (vpc1)
- external (vpc0)
- external (vpc1)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's actually `<vpc name>.<subnet name>.<availability zone>`. That's the format I had to use to get your example dropdown list. It's also the format in this doc and in some online chatter elsewhere: https://docs.armory.io/user-guides/deploying/#vpc-subnet-type